# MongoDB update is slow on an empty collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a Java Spring application that periodically (every 10 seconds) performs an update on my database, a 3 node replica set.

The performance of the update varies substantially between calls. What is surprising is that when the collection is empty I have noticed the following in the logs:

```
2018-01-23T11:02:37.941+0000 I COMMAND  [conn18] command myCollection.$cmd command: update { update: "myCollection", ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority" }, updates: [ { q: { lockExpiry: { $lte: 1516705340965 } }, u: { $set: { isLocked: false } }, multi: true } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:115 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 10555ms
```

Any reason why such a query could be taking this long? I am using MongoDB 3.2 with the WiredTiger storage engine, the collection does not have an index.

Comment: You've got writeConcern "majority" specified. Does that mean you're running against a replica set - and could the delay be due to latency between the nodes perhaps?

Comment: That is a good point, I never considered network latency. I am indeed running a 3 node replica set.

Comment: I've turned it into an answer; it's still speculative, but may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running against a replica set, and you've got writeConcern "majority" specified. Could the delay be due to latency between the nodes perhaps?

Comment: After further investigation I strongly believe that the issues I have encountered can be attributed to a combination of: network latency, incorrect indices and application contention when running multiple queries in parallel